# Prove that $f$ is continuous only at $x=0$

Tags: limits, functions, proof-explanation, continuity

I cannot understand the solution to this problem given in my book.

**Problem**: Consider function $f$ defined for all $x$ by $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is irrational and $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational. Prove that $f(x)$ is continuous only at $x=0$.

**Solution given in book**: Recall that, arbitrarily close to any given real number, there are rational as well as irrational numbers.
The function $f$ is continuous at $a = 0$, because $|f (x) − f (0)|=|f (x) − 0|=|f (x)|≤|x|$ for any
$x$, so $f (x) → f (0)$ as $x → 0$. If $a \neq 0$ is rational, then $|f (x) − f (a)|=|f (x)|$, which is equal to $|x|$ when $x$ is irrational. But if $a\neq 0$ is irrational, then $|f (x) − f (a)|=|f (a)|$ whenever $x$ is rational. In
either case, $f(x)$ does not approach $0$ as $x$ approaches $a$. It follows that $f$ is discontinuous for all $x = 0$.

I do not specifically understand the part where it shows that $f(x)$ is not continuous at any $x$ other 
$0$. I would be very grateful if anybody could throw some light on this part as well as the last part of the proof that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$. How does the inequality give the conclusion that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Are you **sure** that your book says “If $a=0$ is irrational”? If so, then I urge you to throw it away.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, sorry, that was a typing mistake. It should have been $\neq$. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the continuity at $0$, since you always have $|f(x)|\leqslant|x|$, then, given $\varepsilon>0$, if $\delta=\varepsilon$, then$$|x|<\delta\iff|x|<\varepsilon\implies|f(x)|<\varepsilon.$$

If $a\ne0$ and $a$ is rational, then $|f(x)-f(a)|=|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|$, which is equal to $|x|$ if $x\notin\Bbb Q$. So, if $|x-a|<\frac{|a|}2$, $|f(x)|=|x|>\frac{|a|}2$ and therefore $|f(x)|$ is *not* arbitrarily close to $0$, as it should be, if $f$ was continuous at $a$.

Can you understand the other case now?

Comment: Could you please explain "if $|x-a|<\frac{|a|}{2}, |f(x)|=|x|>\frac{|a|}{2}$"?

Comment: If $|x-a|<\frac{|a|}2$, then\begin{align}|x|&=|x-a+a|\\&\geqslant\bigl||x-a|-|a|\bigr|\\&=|a|-|x-a|\text{ (since $|x-a|<|a|$)}\\&>|a|-\frac{|a|}2\\&=\frac{|a|}2.\end{align}

Comment: According to the negation of the epsilon-delta definition of continuity, $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=a$ if we can find a $\epsilon>0$ such that, for all $\delta>0$, there exists a number $x$ satisfying $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(a)|\geq\epsilon$. Does this proof take all $\delta$ into account? Also, why are we choosing $a$ and $x$ to be one rational and one irrational, that is, of different types?

Comment: Yes, it takes that into account; in this case, the $\varepsilon$ is $\frac{|a|}2$. And we choose one rational and another irrational so that we are able to find a $x$ such that $|x-a|<\delta|$ and that $|f(x)-f(a)|\geqslant\frac{|a|}2$.

Comment: I cannot understand how does it take all $\delta$ into account? Could you please explain?

Comment: If we take $\delta=\frac{3|a|}{4}$, then $|x|>\frac{|a|}{4}$. In this case $|x|$ may not be greater than $\frac{|a|}{2}$.

Comment: Say that $a$ is rational. Given $\delta>0$, there is an irrational number $x$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ and that $|x-a|<\frac{|a|}2$. But then $|f(x)-f(a)|>\frac{|a|}2=\varepsilon$.